# Why is the IonIcon component throwing an error but no the Text component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to React Native and this is my main App.js component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import { Ionincons} from '@expo/vector-icons'

export class App extends React.Component {
  render (){
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
       <Ionincons name='ios-pizza'/>
  </View>
  )
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  }
})
```

When I try to run this simple code, I get the following message:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: %s.%s%s, undefined,  You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

But when I swap the *IonIcons* component with a simple
`<Text>Hello</Text/>` everything works just fine.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You have a misspelling, `Ionincons` should be `Ionicons`:

```
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
```

and

```
<Ionicons name='ios-pizza'/>
```